# Cropping on server side vs cropping on client and sending base64 string?

Tags: javascript, html, image, canvas

I want to allow my users to upload images in particular size constraints so cropping is needed. Now I found two plugins one is [jcrop](http://deepliquid.com/content/Jcrop_Implementation_Theory.html) and the other is [cropper](https://github.com/fengyuanchen/cropper); 
`Jcrop` uses a server side approach to crop images. Here is snippet from their docs:

> A typical workflow for cropping functionality in a web application
>   looks like this:
>
> Upload or select an image to crop. 
>   Display page with cropping interface.
>   Capture selected coordinates as form values On form submission.
>   Server performs image crop. Resultant image is saved, replaced, updated,
>   displayed, etc

While `cropper` use `HTML5 canvas` to crop images on client side and send `base64` string to server where server can decode it as an image and save it.

I personally like the second approach more as i can send the string inside `json` helping me avoid `multipart form data` content type, I can continue using the `application/json` content type.
However after reading the jcrop approach I am concerned about performance of client side cropping technique. Which approach will give better performance, and cover mobile devices? What are the limitations to each approach like max file size etc..

Comment: If you're supporting mobile devices, you might give the mobile user a downsized version of the image to set their cropping coordinates and then do the actual cropping on the server. I suggest this both because of the smaller display size and because canvas performance on mobile is much less than on a fully powered desktop.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I cannot speak about specific implementation performance or file size limits, but I am fairly certain that the desired approach here would be having **both** client- and server-side cropping, implemented thusly:

1. If client is able to, crop it client-side
2. Client sends to server whatever it's got (cropped if able to crop, uncropped otherwise)
3. Server inspects what it received. If dimensions are greater than accepted, crop it server-side.

This is because even if you decided to implement client-side only, you would be a fool to trust that you'll never receive noncompliant data from your users. Since you're forced by that fact of life to make server-side validation anyway, that is a great opportunity to transparently crop big images, ensuring compliance regardless of the client's capabilities.

I wouldn't worry about client-side performance. 1 or 2 seconds of non-responsiveness when sending the picture wouldn't kill anyone.

About maximum file size, this is also not an issue in this approach, because you ensure the client sends the smaller version it can send. If it cannot crop and the image is too big, it won't be able to send it to you anyway.

Comment: "If dimensions are greater than accepted, crop it server-side." But that would not be the same as user cropping it. I need to send the coordinates to server in that case.

Comment: @Kasahs I see. Then I assume the client will never send coordinates, because it is always assumed it will crop. The solution then may be the server doing *resizing* instead of *cropping*, which doesn't take coordinates and the result is pretty acceptable, considering it's the client's fault for sending wrong data. That is graceful handling of a problem that should happen rarely.

Answer (score 0):

We cannot trust blob data of cropped image sent by the client to the server so it is always better to take values only from client side and validate from both sides and do processing in server side as much as possible.